# Google Play shows an error: Your administrator has not given you access to this item

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app on Google Play Console. Atm the testing method is set to `Closed Beta Testing` and we have a list of users to test it. Looks like this: [image]

I have my mail in the list of testers and shared myself a link. When I follow it, this page is presented:

[image]

When I follow the link, I can see the app on Google Play. The page contains also 2 messages:

`Your administrator has not given you access to this item`

`You're a beta tester for this app. Future updates will include beta versions`

There is no install button. As I understand, the issue is with the first message about access. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message is displayed if you're using Managed Google Play to distribute your app privately, targeting it to organisations - this can be verified by navigating to Store Presence > Pricing & distribution > User programs. When distributing a private app using a closed track you also have to add the organisations under the "Manage testers" section - these aren't automatically added when you create a track.

[image: Screenshot of the "Organisations" subsection on the Google Play Store Console]